# How to style MUI slider?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Slider from "@mui/material/Slider";

function valuetext(value) {
  return `${value}°C`;
}

export default function RangeSlider() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([20, 37]);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: 300 }}>
      <Slider
        getAriaLabel={() => "Temperature range"}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        getAriaValueText={valuetext}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

How to make range within the thumb and the thumb green and the range outside of both thumbs a lighter green?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include these classes in your CSS file. Track corresponds to the range between thumbs and rail is the range outside both thumbs.

```
.MuiSlider-thumb{
  color: green;
}
.MuiSlider-rail{
  color:lightgreen;
}
.MuiSlider-track{
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: how does this work?

Answer (score 6):

You can customize your slider with [styled](https://mui.com/system/styled/#main-content) utility:

```
const green500 = "#228b22";
const green900 = "#7FFF00";

const CustomSlider = styled(Slider)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: green500, //color of the slider between thumbs
  "& .MuiSlider-thumb": {
    backgroundColor: green500 //color of thumbs
  },
  "& .MuiSlider-rail": {
    color: green900 ////color of the slider outside  teh area between thumbs
  }
}));
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-slider-nghp7?file=/demo.tsx:160-215)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to define the custom styles.

```
const CustomSliderStyles = {
    '& .MuiSlider-thumb': {
        color: "#749761"
    },
    '& .MuiSlider-track': {
        color: "#749761"
    },
    '& .MuiSlider-rail': {
        color: "#acc4e4"
    },
    '& .MuiSlider-active': {
        color: "#f5e278"
    }
};
```

Then to use them

```
<Slider sx={CustomSliderStyles} />
```